# Rational with minimal denominator between two rationals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

My question from an easy problem.

> $p,q$ are positive integers such that $$
> \frac{5}{9}<\frac{p}{q}<\frac{4}{7}
> $$ find $p,q$ such that $q$ is the smallest number that satisfies this inequality.

Draw the line of $ y<\frac{9}{5}x$ and $y>\frac{7}{4}x$ , we can "observe" that $\frac{9}{16}$ is such number.

However, if the question becomes

> $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers such that $$\frac{a}{c}<\frac{b}{d}
> $$ find $p$,$q$ such that $q$ is the smallest number that satisfies the inequality

$$\frac{a}{c}<\frac{p}{q}<\frac{b}{d}$$

No idea about this.

Comment: now try denominators from 2 to 15.

Comment: $\frac59\lt\frac pq\lt\frac47$ is not an equation. An equation has an $=$ sign in it.

Comment: Those who are familiar with Farey Sequences will solve this immediately. If $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Z^+$ with $a/b<c/d$ and $ ***\; (bc-ad)=1 \; ***\; $ then every $x\in \Bbb Q\cap (a/b,c/d)$ is expressed in lowest terms as $x=(ma+nc)/(mb+nd)$ for  unique $m,n \in \Bbb Z^+.$ So $mb+nd\ge b+d,$ with equality iff $m=n=1.$ So in the Q, $p/q=(5+4)/(9+7)=9/16.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet great! Farey sequence can perfectly be applied to this question. Did not spot that before lol.

Comment: @camhunter I think you'll find it's the same solution.

Comment: Since $a/b$ is in a very restricted range, ab will be strongly correlated with b so that minimizing the former would likely minimize the latter. Here, $b≥17$ with $ab≤144$ would force $a≤8$ contradicting $a/b>5/9$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do we get with continued fractions?

$\dfrac{5}{9}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{4}}}$

$\dfrac{4}{7}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{3}}}$

The fractions are identical until we get to the last layer where one has a $4$ and the other has a $3$.  Were there an integer between $3$ and $4$ we could replace the last layer with the smallest such integer, following the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352861/what-is-the-smallest-possible-value-of-q-such-that-frac710-fracpq?r=SearchResults).

We don't have such an integer between $3$ and $4$ so this does not appear to work.  But we can force the issue by rendering

$4=3+\dfrac{1}{1}$

$3=3+\dfrac{1}{M}$

where $M$ is taken as approaching infinity.  Then we have

$\dfrac{5}{9}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{1}}}}$

$\dfrac{4}{7}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{M}}}}$

Now we put $2$ as the smallest integer between $1$ and $M$ to get an intervening fraction with a minimal denominator.  Thus

$\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{2}}}}=\dfrac{9}{16}$

Comment: Thanks! This is a brilliant method!

Comment: Apparently not brilliant enough for some people.